# Searched ID is not found even though it is in the array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I want to be prompted for my ID when calling the component, and then this ID should be searched in my "Members" array. Unfortunately, I always receive the message in the console that no member with the ID was found, even though it exists. What could be the problem?

```js
useEffect(() => {
  Api.getMe().then(response => {
    const MyID = response.data.id;
    const memberExists = Mitglieder.some((member) => member.id === MyID);
    console.log('Eigene ID:', MyID); // MyID
    console.log('Mitglieder:', Mitglieder); // Memberlist
    console.log('Erstes Mitglied ID: ', Mitglieder[0].member.id);  // First Member ID

    if (memberExists) {
      console.log(`Mitglied mit der ID ${MyID} existiert.`); // Member exists
      return true;
    } else {
      console.log(`Kein Mitglied mit der ID ${MyID} gefunden.`); // Member does not exist
      return false;
    }

  }).catch(error => {
    console.error('Fehler beim Abrufen der ID:', error);
  });
}, []);
```

Comment: The` useEffect` might not wait for the promise to be resolved before checking the existence of the member. Be sure that  you await its resolution.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a strict equality check, e.g. `===` to compare a `member.id` value to a `MyID` value. If these two values are different types then the comparison will fail. This is sometimes the case when trying to compare between id values that are number-to-string or vice-versa.

Example comparisons:

```js
console.log("5 === '5'", 5 === "5");     // false
console.log("'5' === 5", "5" === 5);     // false
console.log("'5' === '5'", "5" === "5"); // true
console.log("5 === 5", 5 === 5);         // true
```

You will want to use a type-safe comparison, e.g. number-to-number or string-to-string.

```js
console.log("String(5) === '5'", String(5) === "5"); // true
console.log("Number('5') === 5", Number("5") === 5); // true
```

Comparing string-to-string is usually safer since it covers both strings and number values.

```js
useEffect(() => {
  Api.getMe()
    .then(response => {
      const MyID = String(response.data.id);

      const memberExists = Mitglieder.some(
        (member) => String(member.id) === MyID
      );

      console.log('Eigene ID:', MyID);
      console.log('Mitglieder:', Mitglieder);
      console.log('Erstes Mitglied ID: ', Mitglieder[0].member.id);

      if (memberExists) {
        console.log(`Mitglied mit der ID ${MyID} existiert.`);
      } else {
        console.log(`Kein Mitglied mit der ID ${MyID} gefunden.`);
      }
      return memberExists;
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error('Fehler beim Abrufen der ID:', error);
    });
}, []);
```